# Probability of a letter coming from a city

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got this question:

> A letter is known to have come either from $\text{TATANAGAR}$ or from $\text{CALCUTTA}$. On the envelope just two consecutive Letters $\text{TA}$ are visible. What is the probability that the letters came from $\text{TATANAGAR}$?

My attempt:

Total number of cases $=3$, as there are three such pairs.

Probability $={{\text{Favourable}}\over{\text{Total}}}=\frac23$

However, the answer is given to be $7\over11$.

How is this possible? Please help.

Comment: This can only be solved if the ratio $P(\text{comes from TATANAGAR}):P(\text{comes from CALCUTTA})$ is known. I suspect the events are meant to be equiprobable but in the wording of the question that is not explicit enough.

Comment: @drhab This is right: imagine that there are very few letters ever (practically zero) coming from Tatanagar, you would immediately expect this letter (like the bulk of the other letters) to have come from Calcutta. I've provided an answer below, in which we first calculate the probability in terms of those two probabilities, and then, in the end, we replace them with $\frac12$.

Comment: Also, maybe it rains more heavily in Tatanagar so, even if there are few letters from Tatanagar, they make up the bulk of those letters where only a pair of consecutive letters is preserved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T$ be the event that the letter with two consecutive letters preserved came from Tatanagar, $C$ the event that the letter came from Calcutta, and $X$ the event that the letter came with exactly the pair of letters "TA" on the address.

First, note that we have:

$$P(X\mid T)=\frac{2}{8}=\frac{1}{4}$$

because there are $8$ pairs of consecutive letters in the 9-letter word TATANAGAR, and $2$ of them are "TA". Here, the assumption is that, in a word, *all consecutive pairs of letters are equally likely to be preserved*.

Similarly, $P(X\mid C)=\frac{1}{7}$ because there is only one pair "TA" in the 8-letter word CALCUTTA.

Now, applying Bayes' formula, we have:

$$P(T\mid X)=\frac{P(X\cap T)}{P(X)}=\frac{P(X\mid T)P(T)}{P(X\mid T)P(T)+P(X\mid C)P(C)}$$

which, by replacing above calculated $P(X\mid T)$ and $P(X\mid C)$ gives:

$$P(T\mid X)=\frac{\frac{1}{4}P(T)}{\frac{1}{4}P(T)+\frac{1}{7}P(C)}$$

Now, they apparently also assume that $P(T)=P(C)=\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. that *a priori you have equally many letters with just two consecutive letters preserved coming from Tatanagar as from Calcutta* (is that true?- doesn't matter...), so we finally have:

$$P(T\mid X)=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{7}{11}$$

**Note**: I've been careful to write, in the above answer, the hidden assumptions from the problem *in italic*. I'd be much happier with the problem statement if they were explicitly spelled out...

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_1$ be the event of the letter coming from TATANAGAR, $E_2$ be the event it came from CALCUTTA, and $A $ be the event that denotes two consecutive alphabets visible are TA.

Given: $$P (E_1)=P (E_2)=\frac12$$ $$ P (A \mid E_1) = \frac28, P (A \mid E_2)=\frac17$$ because there are two occurrences of TA in TATANAGAR in eight pairs (letters **should be consecutive**, hence TR isn't counted), and $1$ in CALCUTTA with seven pairs..

Conclude using Bayes' theorem.

Comment: However, the answer is given to be 7/11.

Comment: I don't see how the denominator becomes $11$, even with Bayes' theorem.

Comment: that is same like my aanswer 7/9

Comment: @Arthur We need $$P (E_1 \mid A) = \frac {1/8}{11/56} = \frac {7}{11} $$

Comment: @Arthur The denominator has two cases right: $P (E_1)P (A |E_1)+P (E_2)P (A|E_2) $..

Comment: Of course. Each of the seven possible pairs from Calcutta is slightly more probable than each of the eight possible pairs from Tatanagar. How silly of me.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot use **2/3** directly is because occurrence of **TA** from both city names in not equally likely.

**TATANAGAR**- Probability of having **TA** is **2/8**

**CALCUTTA** - Probability of having **TA** is **1/7**

Probability it is from **TATANAGAR**= $\frac{1/4}{1/4+1/7}$=$7/11$

Answer (score 1):

$$T\equiv \text{comes from Tatanagar}\quad \text{and}\quad C\equiv \text{Comes from Calcutta}\rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             p(T)=\dfrac{1}{2} \\
             \\ p(C)=\dfrac{1}{2}
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
$$\text{Possible choices of two consecutive letters:}\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \text{In TATANAGAR}: 8 \\
             \\ \text{In CALCUTTA}: 7
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
$$\text{Event} D\equiv \text{The chosen couple of letters is TA}\rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             p(D|T)=\dfrac{2}{8} \\
             \\ p(D|C)=\dfrac{1}{7}
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
$$p(T|D)=\dfrac{p(T\cap D)}{p(D)}=\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{8}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{7}}=\dfrac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{7+4}{56}}=\dfrac{7}{11}$$

Comment: How is the possible choice of consecutive letters 8?