# Bayes' Theorem: Finding the probability of choosing a trick coin given the result is a tail

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

A trick coin with two tails is put in a jar with three normal coins. One coin is selected at random and tossed. If the result is a tail, what is the probability that the trick coin was selected?

**My Attempt:**

Let $A$ be the event of obtaining a tail and let $B$ be the event that the coin is fair.

So we have $P(A) = 0.5$ and $P(B) = 0.75$. Therefore, $P(\bar{A}) = 0.5$ and $P(\bar{B}) = 0.25$.

Now, I know that we need to use the [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) here to find $P(A|\bar{B})$. The problem is I am not sure how to find $P(\bar{B}|A)$ that is used in the equation. Can someone please explain to me how to find that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the event that we had a tail, $F$ the event that the coin is fair and $K$ the event that the coin is the trick coin.

$$P(K|T)=\frac{P(K\cap T)}{P(T)}=\frac{P(K\cap T)}{P(T\cap F)+P(T\cap K)}=\frac{P(T|K)P(K)}{P(T|F)P(F)+P(T|K)P(K)}$$

where we have $P(T|K)=1, P(T|F)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(K)=\frac{1}{4}, P(F)=\frac{3}{4}$. Replacing those values, we get:

$$P(K|T)=\frac{1\times \frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{3}{4}+1\times \frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{5}{8}}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: And $P(T) = P(T\cap F)+P(T\cap K)$ because $F$ and $K$ are disjoint and complementary events.

Comment: @Sasha That is correct. In some courses actually they teach you a more general formula ("extended Bayes formula", see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Extended_form), which you can then use for $n$ disjoint events that cover the whole probability space.

Comment: See also a very similar problem that just came through maybe a week ago on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588726/probability-of-a-letter-coming-from-a-city

Answer (score 0):

I know you have to use Bayes' Theorem but still it's easier to look at the tail set since we know we get a tail and  consider the favorables cases for the trick coin $C=2$ the number of all tails $A=5$ so $P=\frac C A=\frac 2 5$.